# Open website in new tab for aspx

Tags: asp.net

i want to open **the website in new tab** using aspx
this is my code:-

```
   hlWebsite.Text = "<a href='http://" + objStudent.Website + "'  OnClientClick='aspnetForm.target ='_blank''> " + objStudent.Website + "</a>";
```

current code it open in same browser. i want open in new tab 
can any body help me.
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control whether a new window is opened as a tab, or a window. This is a user preference. If you specify dimensions of the window via a javascript `window.open` then you'll get a new window, but you can't force a tab

Comment: open the new tab. my code only can open at the same page. can you make my code it open in new tab.

Comment: I also suggest not forcing a new tab or window to open. This can affect the user experience and if user don't like your website, they won't return.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do this if `hlWebsite` is a Hyperlink:

```
 hlWebsite.Text = objStudent.Website;
 hlWebsite.NavigateUrl = objStudent.Website;
 hlWebsite.Target = "_blank";
```

Comment: can not function.. for your info. my code is open the website, but it open at the same windows. so my system it go to new website because it is open at the same windows. can you edit my code to make it open in new tab... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a `Label`? An `Hyperlink` would be better suited :

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" Target="_blank" id="hlWebsite" />
```

and

```
hlWebsite.NavigateUrl = objStudent.Website;
hlWebsite.Text = objStudent.Website;
```

Anyways, you previous code was not working because OnClienClick is a server property. You are writing raw html, thus this attribute were rendered as is in the html output (and ignored by the browser).

<s>You may change this to :</s>

```
hlWebsite.Text = "<a href='http://" + objStudent.Website + "'  target='_blank'> " + objStudent.Website + "</a>";
```

(Removed, because the Text property will be html encoded before rendered).

But I think the 1st approach is more clear.

Comment: can not function.. for your info. my code is open the website, but it open at the same windows. so my system it go to new website because it is open at the same windows. can you edit my code to make it open in new tab... Thanks a lot.